# How to match the string having special characters like hyphen

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a sample documents having values of `word` as:

```
{'word': 'key-value'}
{'word': 'acid-base'}
```

May I know how can I match the `'key-value'` by `'key value'` also `'acid-base'` as `'acid base'`

Here I am trying to match the word with having space instead of a hyphen

ref SO , I tried using an escaping character match as :

```
$match:{ 'word':/\-acid base/ }
```

But this didn't work , Any help is appreciated TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{'word':{ $regex: /acid.base/ }}
```

The above mentioned regex should probably solve your problem for having a single special character between the words

Comment: *single special character , i.e., matches for only one special character ? if had a string 'acid-base-reflux' then this is done as `/acid.base.reflux/` ?

Comment: Yes @Codenewbie as mentioned above the Answer would match for only one single character (Not necessary a special character, any character excluding a space would be accepted )

For a single special character
     `/acid[-*@!#%&()^~{}\/\\]base/`
To include any other character, just include it with the list.


Yes, you're right,  for a String like  'acid-base-reflux' 
`/acid.base.reflux/` would be the right approach.